# Fatal error running linear regression with many terms on RHS

Tags: r, lm

When running an `lm`, RStudio gives me a fatal error and restarts my session.  My source data has several factor columns that get broken up into several hundred dummy variables each.  The below `ld.vars`, which pulls out the linearly dependent dummy variables, has 363 entries.  So, my overall regression equation has hundreds of terms on the RHS; all columns, dummies, and then subtracting the linearly dependent dummies:

y = (all x variables including every dummy variable automatically generated) - (363 linearly dependent dummy variables)

Is the length of the RHS the source of my fatal error?

My attempt is below, using code from [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885160/vifs-returning-aliased-coefficients-in-r).

**Code**

```
library(car)

load(‘full_data.rda’)

## build original regression with all dummy variables included
formula <- as.formula(paste0("Closing.Cost ~ ", paste(colnames(full_data[-19]), collapse=' + ')))
reg3 <- lm(formula, full_data)

## this line produces a warning: "prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading"
predict(reg3, newdata=full_data[106,], interval="prediction")

## this line produces an error: "Error in vif.default(reg3) : there are aliased coefficients in the model"
vif(reg3)

## find the linearly dependent variables
ld.vars <- attributes(alias(reg3)$Complete)$dimnames[[1]]
ld.vars <- paste0("`", ld.vars, "`")

## remove the linearly dependent variables
formula.new <- as.formula(paste0(formula, " - ", paste0(ld.vars, collapse = " - "), collapse = " - "))

## run new model: this line produces a fatal error
reg4 <-lm(formula.new, full_data)

## assess collinearity of new regression (haven't been able to run this line)
vif(reg4)
```

```
> matrix <- model.matrix(formula, full_data)
> dim(matrix)
[1] 4179 1311
```

**I have several factors with hundreds of levels**

```
> total_levels <- full_data %>% purrr::map(levels) %>% map(length)
> Reduce("+", total_levels)
[1] 1271
```

From @BenBolker in the comments, I tried a generalized `lm` with a large number of terms on the RHS (2582 columns, enough to equal the number of terms I'm attempting in my example above).  This worked fine:

```
dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4179*2582),ncol=2582)); m1 <- lm(V1 ~ ., data=dd)
```

**Fatal error** [image: pop-up]

**Session Info** (although this is prior to running the code chunk that throws the fatal error):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] car_3.0-2         carData_3.0-2     rattle_5.2.0      rpart_4.1-13      caret_6.0-81      lattice_0.20-38   DT_0.5           
 [8] plotly_4.8.0      generics_0.0.2    broom_0.5.1       lubridate_1.7.4   janitor_1.1.1     ggrepel_0.8.0     rio_0.5.16       
[15] data.table_1.12.0 forcats_0.4.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.0.1     purrr_0.3.1       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_0.8.3      
[22] tibble_2.0.1      ggplot2_3.1.0     tidyverse_1.2.1   kableExtra_1.0.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 webshot_0.5.1      httr_1.4.0         tools_3.5.2        backports_1.1.3    R6_2.4.0          
 [8] lazyeval_0.2.1     colorspace_1.4-0   nnet_7.3-12        withr_2.1.2        tidyselect_0.2.5   curl_3.3           compiler_3.5.2    
[15] cli_1.0.1          rvest_0.3.2        xml2_1.2.0         bookdown_0.9       scales_1.0.0       digest_0.6.18      foreign_0.8-71    
[22] rmarkdown_1.11     pkgconfig_2.0.2    htmltools_0.3.6    htmlwidgets_1.3    rlang_0.3.1        readxl_1.3.0       rstudioapi_0.9.0  
[29] shiny_1.2.0        jsonlite_1.6       crosstalk_1.0.0    ModelMetrics_1.2.2 zip_2.0.0          magrittr_1.5       Matrix_1.2-15     
[36] Rcpp_1.0.0         munsell_0.5.0      abind_1.4-5        stringi_1.3.1      yaml_2.2.0         MASS_7.3-51.1      plyr_1.8.4        
[43] recipes_0.1.4      grid_3.5.2         promises_1.0.1     crayon_1.3.4       haven_2.1.0        splines_3.5.2      hms_0.4.2         
[50] knitr_1.22         pillar_1.3.1       reshape2_1.4.3     codetools_0.2-15   stats4_3.5.2       glue_1.3.0         evaluate_0.13     
[57] blogdown_0.11      rpart.plot_3.0.6   modelr_0.1.4       httpuv_1.4.5.1     foreach_1.4.4      cellranger_1.1.0   gtable_0.2.0      
[64] assertthat_0.2.0   xfun_0.5           gower_0.2.0        openxlsx_4.1.0     mime_0.6           prodlim_2018.04.18 xtable_1.8-3      
[71] later_0.8.0        class_7.3-14       survival_2.43-3    viridisLite_0.3.0  timeDate_3043.102  iterators_1.0.10   lava_1.6.5        
[78] ipred_0.9-8
```

Comment: If the issue is that you're running out of memory (it might be, I'm not sure), you may want to look into the function `felm` in the `lfe` package.  It uses a method of differences to compute regression coefficients when you have many dummy variables in your model.

Comment: I replaced `lm` with `felm` and got the exact same fatal error result.  The error appears in about 5 seconds after execution.  It seems like if it were a memory issue, my machine would lock up or RSuite would stop responding

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some sample data (with, e.g., `dput()`) that recreates the error so that I can see the issue on my machine?

Comment: Sure, I will attempt to do so later today.

Comment: @DanY I didn't know what `dput()` was until now, but I don't think I can use that to post sample data.  As I mentioned in my edit to the question above, my factor variables have a total of 1271 levels.  Or is there a way to do so that won't create a huge code block here?

Comment: What do you mean by "fatal error"? Put the output that R prints in the question.

Comment: Yes, we **definitely** need to see the error message in order to proceed.

Comment: The raw size of the model shouldn't be a problem; `dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4179*1311),ncol=1311)); m1 <- lm(V1 ~ ., data=dd)` works fine on an old MacBook Pro ...

Comment: @HongOoi please see screenshot attached above. I believe this qualifies for the `fatal error` tag!